# Gstreamer "qtdemux" and "ffdec_h264"

Tags: gstreamer

how can I connect "qtdemux"  and "ffdec_h264" using c code with Gstreamer ?

demux= gst_element_factory_make("qtdemux", "demux");

dec = gst_element_factory_make ("ffdec_h264", "dec");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using 0.10.x? Gst 1.x doesn't have ffmpeg elements.

Here are the steps:

- You will have to attach a callback to "pad-added" signal of the qtdemux.
- The callback will be invoked from the qtdemux for every stream
  (eg. audio,video) present in the source.
- The pad connection will have to be done inside the callback.

Go to page 32 on
https://lzy-s-prct.googlecode.com/files/gstreamer-manual.pdf

for the example.